# How do I use this github url?

Tags: url, github, gist

I just uploaded a little coding project  I was working on at gist.github because it seemed like a nice fast way of uploading a couple of classes at once.

I want to link someone to my "gist" and in the corner it says:

`Public Clone URL: git://gist.github.com/824082.git`

`Private Clone URL: git@gist.github.com:824082.git`

So figure I want the public clone url but obviously it looked strange. Upon clicking on it I get this popup:

> Give this clone URL to anyone.
>   `git clone git://gist.github.com/824082.git gist-824082`

I'm flummoxed, how is this supposed to work exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every gist you write is actually contained in it's own git repository on Github. So they can naturally be cloned, and updated the same as every other git repository on github. Just try it, you will find your files inside the cloned git repo.

When linking to a gist to just show it to others, you should just use the URL you see in your browser's address bar.